# How do I add a border to an (8 point star) css shape?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How do I add a red border outside this 8 point star? Or is there a simple svg solution anyone knows of?

**IS:**
[image]
  **NEED:** [image]

[**JS fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v9bqahy8/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="star8"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#star8 {
 border: 3px solid red;
 background: blue; width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(20eg);
 }
#star8:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 80px;
 width: 80px;
 background: blue;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
 }
```

Comment: If you're using `svg` you can just apply a `stroke: <color>` and `stroke-width: <number>`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am just not familiar with how to obtain a svg code similar to something like this: 
<svg viewBox="0 0 75 75" width="200px">
  <path d="m5,22 18,-18 28,0 18,18 0,28 -18,18, -28,0 -18,-18z" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="black" />
</svg>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you may use [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/mix-blend-mode) and eventually the other pseudo : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeMQNr)**

```
#star8:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px red;::* a border works too */
  mix-blend-mode:overlay;
}
```

```css
#star8 {
  margin: 2em;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background: blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

#star8:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: blue;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

#star8:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px red;
  mix-blend-mode:overlay;
}
```

```html
<div id="star8"></div>
```

---

without `mix-blend-mode` but `z-index` and `:after`

```css
#star8 {
  margin: 2em;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background: blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

#star8:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: blue;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px red;
}

#star8:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: blue;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="star8"></div>
```

You can also draw only parts of bg *(via `linear-gradient`)* to hide the border parts unwanted and add some text inside : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KWNmqw

Comment: mix-blend-mode:overlay; i think its not support on all browser

Comment: @kumar, nop, just like the use to be border-radius, display:table-cell; and so many others in their time and many others today ;)  ... but transform won't work either with older browsers so not a big deal to miss the blend-mode

Comment: Yes i will not use oldest browser but in ie11/10 or edge look like this http://prntscr.com/9n7p1e due to blend mode. I have up-vote your answer because its simple and nice technique.

Comment: @kumar maybe the way (nowdays) would be to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports in order to use those fresh css properties and serve to unready browsers an SVG as the other great answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644437/how-do-i-add-a-border-to-an-8-point-star-css-shape/34652954#34652954   ( tutorial here http://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-css-supports-rule-feature-queries/ )

Answer (score 7):

## SVG solution

This can be created with a single svg path.
Adding outline can be done with adding a stroke property to the path

```html
<svg viewBox="-1 -1 50 50" width="200px">
  <path d="M 35,40 30,48 21,42 11,44 9,34 0,30 6,20 4,10 14,8 20,0 28,5 38,3 l 1,10 8,5 -5,8 2,10z" stroke="red" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the div looks the way it does currently is that you don't actually have an 8 pointed star, you have 2 squares superimposed on one another.

The first step is to add the outline to the :before pseudo class. The second is to add an :after pseudo class with no outline, rotated to the same position as the original div, to cover the outline drawn by :before overlapping the original div.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hj1eh6md/

and CSS:

```
#star8 {
 border: 3px solid red;
 background: olive; 
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(20eg);
}
#star8:before {
 border: 3px solid red;
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 80px;
 width: 80px;
 background: olive;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
}
#star8:after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 80px;
 width: 80px;
 background: olive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just overlay another rect over it in :after, covering up the red border.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbrQZa

```
#star8:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: blue;
}
```

You should also make `#star8:before` only 77x77 in size to make it fit.